# getting error in Beautiful Binary String in hackerrank

Tags: java

> I am solving Beautiful Binary String problem in hackerrank but getting error may be my logic is not correct below is problem
>   [Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/815c9.png)

below is my logic which is checking three if conditions for the given binary string '010'.It contains minimumSteps variable which is counting the number of '010'

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    // Complete the beautifulBinaryString function below.
   // static String b;
        static int beautifulBinaryString(String b) {
            int minimumSteps=0;
            for(int i=0;i<b.length();)
                {  
                    if(b.charAt(i)=='0' && b.charAt(i+1)=='1' && b.charAt(i+2)=='0')
                        {
                            minimumSteps++;
                            if((i+3)<b.length())
                            {
                            i=i+3; 
                            }
                        }
                    else
                        {
                        break;
                        }
            }
        return minimumSteps;
        }
    // static boolean containChar(int i)
    // {
    //     if(b.charAt(i)=='')
    //     {

    //     }
    // }

    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));

        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

        String b = scanner.nextLine();

        int result = beautifulBinaryString(b);

        bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(result));
        bufferedWriter.newLine();

        bufferedWriter.close();

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your problem with the description of what you already tried.

Comment: @Neo problem is given in form of image

Answer (score 0):

**Java 8**

> *Initial Thoughts*: We could use a greedy approach and starting from the left everytime we see a 010 replace the last 0 with a 1 and
>   continue

Examples:

```
01010
01110 -> 1
0100101010
0110101010
0110111010
0110111011 -> 3
```

java 1.8

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    String s = input.nextLine();
    int count= 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length()-2; i++)
    {
        if(s.charAt(i) == '0' && s.charAt(i+1) == '1' && s.charAt(i+2) == '0')
        {
            count++;
            i += 2;
        }
    }

   System.out.println(count); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Hope it helps..For any doubts or further clarification comment out your thoughts pls.